# PHPMailler não envia se emails de envio e de autenticação forem NÃO os mesmos

Tags: php

Bom, primeiramente quero dizer que já pesquisei em todos os lugares mas não encontrei uma resposta que funcionasse Apenas tentativas sem sucesso pela web.

Estou falando do **PhPMailler**.

Preciso enviar **e-mails** autenticados à partir do **site**.

Porém tenho mais uma ***dificuldade***: o **e-mail** que envia (From) nem sempre será o que passa na **autenticação** (caixa Postal Servidor Email) do **servidor**.

Hospedo no **UOL Host** e quando o **e-mail** de envio é o mesmo da **autenticação** dá certo.

Queria saber se existe uma maneira de contornar esse problema.

Segue o que eu fiz:

***Obs.:*** **o include da classe é feita em outro arquivo**

**Em tempo**: Outra coisa que gostaria de saber também é como configurar uma conta do tipo `naoresponda@..`. para ***NÃO*** receber **mensagens** igual recebemos **e-mails** aí com remetente `nãoresponda`?

```
<?php

  class EmailEnviarDao {

    public function __construct() {}

    public function enviaEmail($email, $constantes)  {

      $caixaPostalServidorNome = $constantes->getTituloSite();
      $caixaPostalServidorEmail = "contato@".$constantes->getDominioSite();
      $caixaPostalServidorSenha = "senha";

      $enviaFormularioParaNome = $email->getNomeAlvo();
      $enviaFormularioParaEmail = $email->getEmailAlvo();
      $remetenteNome  = $email->getNomeRemete();
      $remetenteEmail = $email->getEmailRemete();
      $assunto =  $email->getAssunto();   
      $mensagem = $email->getDescricao();

      $mail = new PHPMailer();

      $mail->IsSMTP();
      $mail->SMTPAuth  = true;
      $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
      $mail->Charset   = 'utf8_decode()';
      $mail->Host  = 'smtp.'.substr(strstr($caixaPostalServidorEmail, '@'), 1);
      $mail->Port  = '587';
      $mail->Username  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
      $mail->Password  = $caixaPostalServidorSenha;
/*
      $mail->From  = $remetenteEmail;
      $mail->FromName  = utf8_decode($remetenteNome);
*/
      $mail->From  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
      $mail->FromName  = utf8_decode($caixaPostalServidorNome);
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject  = utf8_decode($assunto);
      $mail->Body  = utf8_decode($mensagem);


      $mail->AddAddress($enviaFormularioParaEmail,utf8_decode($enviaFormularioParaNome));

      if($mail->Send()){

          return array("success"=>1,"errors"=>"0K");

      } else {

          return array("success"=>0,"errors"=>$mail->ErrorInfo);

      } 

    }   

  }

?>
```

Comment: Ainda bem que não funciona. Pensou se os SMTPs aceitassem email de contas não autorizadas? Nestes casos você deve sempre usar uma conta autorizada para o login, independente do FROM: do email. É por isso que muitas malas diretas são identificadas como sendo "De <fulano@example.com> VIA <sicrano@example.net>" - O envio é de um, mas o mailer é outro.

Comment: Talvez eu esteja tão cansado de tentar que nem percebi o real propósito da classe. Mas e quando o usuário que enviar um e-mail para o site através do próprio site tipo quando recebe um link por e-mail para acessar uma página especial de contato  queremos que a tal mensagem vá parta o e-mail do site mas sabendo o e-mail de quem enviou?

Comment: São 3 endereços "principais" de envio: O FROM é quem enviou. O SMTP precisa de uma conta válida. E o reply-to é um email alternativo para respostas, caso seja diferente do from. Nem todo mailer aceita envio em nome de terceiros. Só que praticamente todas as hospedagens boas tem algum sistema para envio do email localmente, sem precisar de SMTP externo. Tem que ver qual é a melhor situação para o seu caso.

Comment: Muitas vezes é o caso de perguntar para o suporte da hospedagem como proceder nesses casos. Como eu passo bem longe desse aí que você usa, não conseguiria ajudar com o caso específico, mas acho que eles devem ter algum tipo de atendimento e/ou helpdesk para clientes..

Comment: Entendi. Mas sim. Tem uma conta de e-mail da hospedagem que faz a autenticação. O que eu quero é que o From seja qualquer um. E não ficar atrelado ao e-mil da autenticação.

Comment: Seria o caso de testar outro SMTP, nem que apenas para avaliação (exemplo, uma conta genérica do gmail) para ver se o problema persiste. Aí ao menos elimina a hipótese do problema ser na aplicação.

Comment: já testei:> mesmo problema.

Comment: Mas testou separando no código? O problema do seu código acima é que você usa a mesma variável nos 2 lugares, ai não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: No seu caso tem que por `$mail->Username  = 'credencial@fixa.e.valida'`, separado do from

Comment: como assim? Viu lá o $mail->From? tem um setado para a conta da autenticação e que está funcionando e uma linha $mail->From que está comentada e que é realmente o e-mail que quero enviar e que vem do form.

Comment: Justamente. Separe as coisas. Username não tem que usar a mesma variavel do from. O username é sempre a conta correta do SMTP

Comment: Mas é isso que estou falando. Se eu colocar outra e-mail aí no From dá erro. Só envia se o From for o mesmo da autenticação. Ou seja: desta forma está enviando. Mas só enviar com o from sendo o autenticador. Se o from for por exemplo um e-mail do meu visitante enviando para mim, não vai de jeito nenhum!

Comment: Olhando no seu código, a variavel está a mesma. Não sei se você testou o que eu disse, mas no Username você deveria testar com uma string fixa, e nao uma variável (entendi que se difere nao envia, mas a questão é tambem se está usando a correta quando difere)

Comment: Estou dizendo isso, pq eu nunca vi esse problema acontecer em nenhum dos mailers que eu uso (google, outlook, zoho, etc). e é muito normal eu usar From diferente da autenticação.

Comment: $caixaPostalServidorEmail recebe contato@".$constantes->getDominioSite() e $constantes->getDominioSite() nunca muda. Você está me falando para eu tirar o $constantes->getDominioSite() e colocar direto com uma string o endereço correto?

Comment: Não. Estou dizendo para fazer `$mail->Username  = 'email@queautentica.com';` sem variável nenhuma, independente do resto - aqui vai o email que deu certo. Mesmo que o resto mude

Comment: se for isso, já testei tb e não funcionou. Tem como voce postar como resposta uma classe que voce usa apenas mascarando os dados?

Comment: Não prometo, mas se sobrar um tempinho logo mais tento adaptar seu código para alguma conta minha.

Comment: ok, tentei aqui, olha o retorno: 2018-05-18 21:58:10 
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Ai ja nem tem a ver com senha e usuário, nem chegou a conectar.

Comment: Este código https://pastebin.com/xNeLW9Aw funciona (fiz agora, usando o seu código como base, mas o google não considera o From - Entretanto, se der um $mail->SetFrom( 'email', 'nome') o que puser aqui fica certinho no Reply-to - Se eu não usar o SMTP, e sim o mail( ) do PHP, aí fica 100% conforme você queria. O único detalhe nesse ultimo caso, é que tem que setar o registro SPF do DNS, para nao ser considerado spam.

Comment: 2018-05-19 00:17:12 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO localhost<br>
2018-05-19 00:17:12 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br>
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.<br>
2018-05-19 00:17:13 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2018-05-19 00:17:13 <br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting<br>

Comment: Continua sendo problema de conexão com seu servidor. Tem algum dado errado (ou o nome do servidor, ou a porta, ou o método)

Comment: 2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y29udGF0b0BmdW5lcmFyaWFzYW9wZWRyby5uZXQuYnI=
2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: YXV0QDIwMTg=
2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<naoresponda@funerariasaopedro.net.br>
2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<carcleo@oi.com.br>

Comment: 2018-05-19 01:03:15 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 553 5.7.1 <naoresponda@funerariasaopedro.net.br>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user contato@funerariasaopedro.net.br
2018-05-19 01:03:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: carcleo@oi.com.br: <naoresponda@funerariasaopedro.net.br>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user contato@funerariasaopedro.net.br

Comment: e agora? Junta as duas mensagens ok?

Comment: Só mais uma observação ambos emails, o From e o da autenticação pertencem ao dominio do site e as caixas criadas